# TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED setting is True but required twisted modules failed to import

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am getting below error. Can anyone help me solve the issue?

```
2018-07-25 20:31:19 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: tutorial)
2018-07-25 20:31:19 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.3.0, libxml2 2.9.4, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.7.0, Python 3.7.0 (default, Jul 23 2018, 20:22:55) - [Clang 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.3, Platform Darwin-17.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2018-07-25 20:31:19 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders']}
2018-07-25 20:31:19 [scrapy.middleware] WARNING: Disabled TelnetConsole: TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED setting is True but required twisted modules failed to import:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/telnet.py", line 13, in <module>
    from twisted.conch import manhole, telnet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/conch/manhole.py", line 154
    def write(self, data, async=False):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

you can disable the telnet extension on `settings.py` with:

```
TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED=False
```

Or you can remove the Extension all together (also on `settings.py`):

```
EXTENSIONS = {
    ...
    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
    ...
}
```

the `None` on the settings priority disables the extension.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue when using Scrapy with Python 3.7+. The [fix](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/3326) has been  included in [Scrapy 1.6.0](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/releases/tag/1.6.0).

In the meantime, see the [issue report thread](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3143) for details and workarounds.